# Pre-loading checkboxes with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to build a form with a series of checkboxes that represent a polymorphic association between two models in my database. I have `JobDescription` and `ExperienceLevel`. The form is to update a `JobDescription` and has a checkbox for each `ExperienceLevel`. When the form opens in a modal, I want to have the current experience levels checked that are associated with the job.

I've been struggling to figure out how to implement the checkboxes using `ng-repeat` and `ng-model`. My current code renders the checkboxes, but the correct ones are not pre-selected.

Here is my `editJob` method in my controller:

```
$scope.editJob = function(r) {

    var experienceLevels = {};

    r.experience_levels.map(function(r, i){
        experienceLevels[i] = r.name;
    });
    $scope.experienceLevels = experienceLevels;

    $scope.id = r.id;
    $scope.title = r.title;
    $scope.jobFunction = r.role;
    $scope.description = r.description;
    $scope.postingLink = r.posting_link;
    $scope.company = r.company_name;

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/assets/admin/editjob.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: {
            jobForm: function () {
                return $scope.jobForm;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Here is the part of my form with the checkboxes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Experience Level</label>
    <div ng-repeat="experienceLevel in expItems">
        <input type="checkbox" name="experienceLevel.display" 
               ng-model="job.experienceLevels['experienceLevels']" 
               ng-true-value="experienceLevel">
        {{experienceLevel.display}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm still not sure how to pre-select the checkboxes though. They don't appear to be bound to the model.

Comment: Can we see the HTML?  I think that your problem might not involve your server objects but only the Javascript and HTML.

Comment: I just edited my question with the rendered HTML

Comment: Ok, since you've solved part of the problem, I'm going to edit the question to only include the information related to your remaining problem.

Comment: Ok I edited the question.  If I messed up anything, please fix it.  For future reference, it's not necessary to include "Updates" in the post.  Anyone wanting to see the updates will look at the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for the problem. I don't know if it's good practice (would love feedback) but it seems to work the way I want.

In my controller I now pre-assign experience levels like so:

```
$scope.editJob = function(r) {
    var experienceLevels = {};

    r.experience_levels.map(function(r){
        experienceLevels[r.name] = "true";
    });
```

And on my form I decided to bind to `experienceLevel.display` rather than `experienceLevel.key`, like so:

```
<label>Experience Level</label>
<div ng-repeat="experienceLevel in expItems">
    <input type="checkbox" name="experienceLevel.display" ng-model="job.experienceLevels[experienceLevel.display]" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
    {{experienceLevel.display}}
</div>
```

This gives me a params hash that looks like:

```
{
    "id"=>"23",
    "title"=>"Ruby Ninja",
    "jobFunction"=>"Customer Support",
    "description"=>"Awesomesauce!",
    "postingLink"=>"http://www.google.com/",
    "experienceLevels"=>{
        "Entry Level"=>"false", "Manager"=>"true"
    },
    "company"=>"Ice 2 Go",
    "action"=>"update",
    "controller"=>"admin/job_descriptions",
    "job_description"=>{
        "id"=>23, "title"=>"Ruby Ninja", "description"=>"Awesomesauce!"
    }
}
```

I can then look up the `ExperienceLevel` by name in my Rails controller.